# Navigation control (using functions)

Tags: windows-phone-7

My question is a little different to ones I've seen examples with here.

I've got a navigation user control i put on every page.
On a typical page I have my button click events.

```
private void butArtists_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        MainPage mp = frame.Content as MainPage;
        mp.PlayerMenu("Artists");
    }
```

When I'm on MainPage.xaml the code works fine. But when I'm on pgArtists nothing happens. What I'm presuming is happening is the page is getting set but not displayed.

I set breakpoints on the above function and similar functions. Am i right?

So the problem is that when the user control is embedded into pgArtists the frames content is not swtiched back to MainPage.

Comment: If you aren't on the main page, `frame.Content as MainPage` will return `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how page navigation works on Windows Phone. Please check out "[How to: Perform Page Navigation on Windows Phone link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626521%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)".

You should be using the NavigationService which is available from each page, and not directly fiddling with the PhoneApplicationFrame.

Comment: how would i set my function parameters? querystrings?

Comment: Query strings work well for simple data passed between pages. For more complex data, you'll need to use some other way of storing application state that is shared between pages.

Comment: what are these more complex methods?

Comment: The main recommended architectural pattern for Windows Phone is called [MVVM - for example see article on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153(v=vs.92).aspx). In this article there is a static object which contains state which is shared between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this from any page:

```
var uriFragment = @"views/ArtistsView.xaml";
(App.Current.RootVisual as Frame).Navigate(new Uri(uriFragment, UriKind.Relative));
```